# jekyll-docs not installing on macOS

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, jekyll

[Jekyll's document](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/usage/) says,

> If you’re interested in browsing these docs on-the-go, install the
>   `jekyll-docs` gem and run `jekyll docs` in your terminal.

When I tried to install jekyll-docs on my MacBook Air running macOS Sierra, I bumped into the following problem:

```
sunqingyaos-MacBook-Air:myblog sunqingyao$ jekyll docs
You must install the 'jekyll-docs' gem to use the 'jekyll docs' command. 
sunqingyaos-MacBook-Air:myblog sunqingyao$ sudo gem install jekyll-docs
Successfully installed jekyll-docs-3.3.0
Parsing documentation for jekyll-docs-3.3.0
1 gem installed
sunqingyaos-MacBook-Air:myblog sunqingyao$ jekyll docs
You must install the 'jekyll-docs' gem to use the 'jekyll docs' command. 
sunqingyaos-MacBook-Air:myblog sunqingyao$
```

As you can see, rubygems told me it has `successfully installed jekyll-docs-3.3.0`, while `jekyll docs` kept falling. I've restarted the terminal, still not working.

Comment: I'd personally add it to your gem file `gem 'jekyll-docs', '3.3.0'` and then do `bundle install`?  If it's already installed try running `jekyll _3.3.0_ docs`

Comment: You also need to make sure you're using Jekyll 3.3.0 as well.

Comment: @Alan Yeah I was using `jekyll 3.3.1` with `jekyll-docs 3.3.0`, which presumably caused the issue. The problem now is that I'm using other gems(`github-pages (= 114)`) which depends on `jekyll (= 3.3.1)`, so I cannot downgrade jekyll :(

Comment: If you're using the gem method, you could try a `bundle update` but that will update all to the latest versions

Comment: @Alan Updated everything with `bundle update`, still getting the above error, no matter I run `jekyll docs` or `bundle install jekyll docs`

Comment: Try this $ gem install jekyll-docs -v 3.0.3, then $ gem install jekyll -v 3.0.3, then $ jekyll _3.0.3_ docs - sorry for lack of formatting I'm on my phone will edit in a bit

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue.

In my case I had two jekyll gems:

```
sergpank$ gem list jekyll

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

jekyll (3.4.0, 3.3.1)
jekyll-docs (3.3.1)
jekyll-feed (0.8.0)
jekyll-sass-converter (1.5.0)
jekyll-watch (1.5.0)
```

I have simply uninstalled 3.4.0 (because there was no jekyll-docs-3.4.0):

```
sergpank$ gem uninstall jekyll -v 3.4.0
Successfully uninstalled jekyll-3.4.0

---------------------------------------

sergpank$ gem list jekyll

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

jekyll (3.3.1)
jekyll-docs (3.3.1)
jekyll-feed (0.8.0)
jekyll-sass-converter (1.5.0)
jekyll-watch (1.5.0)
```

After what **jekyll docs** was successfully started!

Comment: Looks like the issue is having an installation of Jekyll with a higher version number than the version of Jekyll docs you have installed. (I imagine Jekyll docs and Jekyll have matching version numbers, to indicate which version of Jekyll is being documented.) This should be the accepted answer :)